# Why are Grave Keys Causing CSH to Interpret a String as a Command?

Tags: csh

I have a csh script running a perl script. The command is

```
`./test.pl`
```

This throws an error reading

```
Hello: Command not found.
```

The csh script contains no 'Hello', however the perl script contains a line reading

```
print "Hello world!\n";
```

Removing the grave keys around the original command fixes the error. What is going on?

Comment: what  you're seeing has been how backticks work since at least the Bourne shell was created in ~1977. Just don't use them if you don't need that feature. Just about all shells support backticks for command-substitution. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's what they are suppose to do.

From `man csh` on my system (which is the documentation for `tcsh`):

> **Command substitution**
>
> Command substitution is indicated by a command enclosed in ``'.  The output  from  such  a
>          command  is  broken  into  separate words at blanks, tabs and newlines, and null words are
>          discarded.  The output is variable and command substituted and put in place of the  original string.
>
> Command  substitutions  inside  double  quotes (`"') retain blanks and tabs; only newlines
>          force new words.  The single final newline does not force a new word in any case.   It  is
>          thus possible for a command substitution to yield only part of a word, even if the command
>          outputs a complete line.
>
> By default, the shell since version 6.12 replaces all newline and carriage return  characters  in the command by spaces.  If this is switched off by unsetting csubstnonl, newlines
>          separate commands as usual.

If you assign `Hello World!` to env var `TEST`, then

```
echo $TEST
$TEST
```

would be the same as

```
echo 'Hello' 'World!'
'Hello' 'World!'         # Fails: No program named Hello
```

because `$TEST` is replaced with split version of its content. It's the same here.

```
echo `./test.pl`
`./test.pl`
```

is the same as

```
echo 'Hello' 'World!'
'Hello' 'World!'         # Fails: No program named Hello
```

Comment: I don't follow. I thought it forked off the process to run in the background?

Comment: Nope. The contents of the backticks are executed as a shell command (in the foreground). Its output is captured and the backticks are substituted with the output. Then the command with the (now-substituted) backticks is executed.

Comment: @user3263864, To start a process in the background, append `&`: `./test.pl &`

Comment: I.e., for that command, the shell runs ./test.pl in the foreground and reads its output from a pipe.  It then replaces the back-quoted command with the output of the command, and parses and runs *that* as a command, so that it tries to run the command "Hello world!", which fails because it can't find a command named "Hello".